# Why doesn't my jQuery/JavaScript work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I'm developing a website for a client, and although all jQuery/Javascript code works fine in Chrome (e.g. floating navbar, and smooth scroll when you click a navbar item), none of it seems to work in Safari?

I've looked at other questions on StackOverflow, and the only advice I've found is to use a HTML validator, because Safari can be iffy like that. 
Although I'm in the process of doing that now, I have a feeling it's something deeper, because most of the HTML issues revolve around obsolete center tags.

At the moment, the site is up at: http://www.grahamcafe.net23.net/Padre/index.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. Right now, without code here, the question is off topic

Comment: Hi Isaac, welcome to stackoverflow! You'll usually get a lot better feedback if you isolate a single bit of code that's causing you trouble. You should then post that code so that others can better help you.

Comment: I am getting this in Safari: `21TypeError: $('.inner-link').smoothScroll is not a function. (In '$('.inner-link').smoothScroll({
        offset: -55,
        speed: 800
    })', '$('.inner-link').smoothScroll' is undefined)` - you need to look in the console

Comment: The code should be available if you're able to load the source code of the page, I really have no idea what the problem could be, so I tried to give as much info as possible, and provided the code if necessary, I'm more than happy to answer any questions also

Comment: mplungjan, thanks a lot for your reply, do you have any idea why that would appear on safari, but not on chrome/ie?

Comment: [commenting on previous comment]That is not what I mean. Please visit the [help] to see it is not the idea we leave SO to look at links that can go stale. It is not useful questions for those who come after. In any case you have a clear error in Safari you need to fix. Also you have a really ugly advert on Safari because I do not have an ad blocker - could that be the problem?\

Comment: If I breakpoint at `http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php` I do not get the error. It document.writes a new jQuery!

Answer (score -1):

If I breakpoint at http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php I do not get the error. It document.writes a new jQuery

Try this in script.js

```
var myWrite = document.write;
document.write = function(str) {
  ;//  ignore document.write
}
```

to stop your hoster from wrecking your page with their horrible script. You get what you pay for I believe.

It assumes Safari allows replacing document.write with an anonymous function